# Rails search post by title,body and tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search

Sorry for bad English :)

I ran into a problem in my application. I want to implement a post search by the post title, post text, and its tags, I have a search form and I want ALL posts that contain this word in the title or text or tags to be displayed, but now it works differently, for example, I have 2 posts:

one of them contains the word "hello" in the header, and the other has the tag "hello",
I want both of these posts to be displayed, but now only the one that has the tag is displayed, and the second with the word "hello" in the header is ignored, I don't know why. I know that the problem with my `Post.search` method.

Please help me, thank in advance!

**Here is my code:**

**Post.rb:**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500}
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}
  validates :adress, length: { maximum: 50}

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy

  def self.search(keywords)
      if keywords
        joins(:tags).where("lower (title) ILIKE :value OR 
                            lower (body) ILIKE :value OR  
                            lower (tags.name) ILIKE :value", 
                            value: "%#{keywords.downcase}%")
      else
        all.order("created_at DESC")
      end
  end
end
```

**Post Controller index action:**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:keywords]).uniq
end
```

Comment: Try to use pg_search gem for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following

**Option One**

```
Post.includes(:tags).where("lower (posts.title) ILIKE :value OR 
                       lower (posts.body) ILIKE :value OR 
                       lower (tags.name) LIKE :value", 
                       value: "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%" ).references(:tags)
```

Or something like this direct to your controller index action

**Option Two**

```
def index
    if params[:keywords].present?
        @posts = Post.includes(:tags).where("lower (posts.title) ILIKE :value OR 
                                             lower (posts.body) ILIKE :value OR 
                                             lower (tags.name) LIKE :value", 
                                             value: "%#{params[:keywords].downcase}%" ).references(:tags)
    else
        @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :DESC)
    end
end
```

**Option Three**

```
def index
    if params[:keywords].present?
        @posts = Post.where('true')
        @posts = @posts.where('lower (title) ILIKE' => "%#{params[:keywords]}%")
        @posts = @posts.where('lower (body) ILIKE' => "%#{params[:keywords]}%")
        @posts = @posts.includes(:tags).where('lower (tags.name)' => "%#{params[:keywords]}%")
        @posts = @posts.order(created_at: :DESC).uniq
    else
        @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :DESC)
    end
end
```

For comlex search you can see this [`RailsCast`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql?view=asciicast) tutorial for [`pg_search`](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it !

Comment: Yeah, the first option works great ! thank you again man you're awesome)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of "joins". Now you have "inner join" and when it hits a row in "tags" table it removes from the result the rest. So you would need right/left join instead.